# Why date formats are different in APEX and Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

The date format in Oracle SQL Developer looks like `DD-MON-YY`.

For example `17-OCT-03`.

The date format in APEX looks like `MM/DD/YYYY`.

For example `12/17/1980`.

Why are they different?

This might cause the same SQL query not to work on both applications.

I know that I can avoid such problem by using TO_DATE and TO_CHAR functions but I want to understand the logic behind this problem.

Does every application use its own default date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, every application has it's own date format.

And even every application can have more than one session, each with a different session format specified for DATEs and TIMESTAMPs.

SQL Developer has it's application level settings defined in the Preferences, Database, NLS page. This is how DATEs will appear unless you issue an ALTER SESSION SET... in your SQL Worksheet.

Or, if you always want a specific format regardless of this setting, build it into your query.

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'DAY') today from dual;
```

[image]

Comment: I think it's fairer to say that every session has its own date format.  Your SQL Developer settings may differ from my SQL Developer settings, I may have multiple SQL Developer sessions each with different NLS settings, and the same APEX application may have different sessions with different settings at the same time.

Comment: Mmm, SQLDev has one application setting for NLS...which you can override at the session level...but yeah. Each application will have its own session and own NLS settings

Comment: I've dealt with more than a few cases where people have claimed that "this script works in Application A, not Application B" get very confused when it fails when a different human uses Application A because those humans have set their NLS settings differently.  It's not that it works in SQL Developer, it's that it works in SQL Developer with Jeff Smith's settings rather than SQL Developer with my settings.  Emphasizing that it is a session-level setting not an application level setting helps when one application allows different users to configure their NLS settings differently.

Comment: ok, but the application determines the session level setting...unless the user has overridden that themselves, and that's something they are already aware of.

Answer (score 0):

It's been my experience as well... YES, every Oracle application/tool can have its own default date format, but most just use the default display format set at the database level:

```
SQL> select name, value from v$parameter where name = 'nls_date_format';

NAME                  VALUE
--------------------- ---------------------
nls_date_format       DD-Mon-YY

1 row selected.
```

But I would not characterize this as "a problem"... it is a valuable feature that provides lots of flexibility in displaying and entering dates in Oracle-based applications.

For sure though, if developers don't understand how Oracle dates work and write code such as this:

```
-- BAD Coding
DECLARE
  ld_holiday_date DATE;
BEGIN
  -- Set a date type variable to a string value and
  -- hope that Oracle can figure out what I mean.
  ld_holiday_date := '01-JAN-2022';
END;
```

they are writing *environment specific* code which will definitely not work in another database (or session) that has a different NLS_DATE_FORMAT from the one they wrote their code in.  Furthermore, the code above is having to do an implicit data type conversion (from string to date) which is leaving it up to Oracle to try and figure out what format is in the string.

To write more deterministic code with regard to Oracle dates, developers should definitely use the TO_DATE function.  Here's the bullet proof version of the code snippet above:

```
-- Good Coding
DECLARE
  ld_holiday_date DATE;
BEGIN
  -- I do not care what the NLS date format is in this
  -- database... this code will work everywhere.
  ld_holiday_date := TO_DATE ('01-JAN-2022', 'DD-MON-YYYY');
END;
```